# Quarkus tests inheritance not allowed?

Tags: java, quarkus

Moving some common annotations from a test class to a base one just doesn't work in Quarkus, is this intended or I'm missing something?

This works:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(FunctionalTestProfile.class)
class FrontendControllerTest {...}
```

This doesn't work:

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestProfile(FunctionalTestProfile.class)
public class BaseFunctionalTest {}

class FrontendControllerTest extends BaseFunctionalTest {...}
```

Annotations just don't get applied to child classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@QuarkusTest` and `@TestProfile` annotations are *not* declared `@Inherited`, so this should *not* be expected to work.

Comment: Oh, i see, thanks @Ladicek! Do you know what's the best way around it? Would custom annotation help?

Comment: I _think_ custom annotation would help, because JUnit Jupiter looks for meta-annotations. So if you had an annotation `@MyTest` meta-annotated `@Inherited @QuarkusTest @Whatever`, that should be enough. Note I'm typing this off the top of my head, based purely on my theoretical knowledge -- I never tried it.

Comment: Just tried that - nope, no luck too. Seems like we're doomed for copy-pasting for now 

Comment: @Ladicek should we change that?

Comment: I personally dislike inherited annotations and prefer being explicit, so my opinion is that we shouldn't change that :-) I still think that custom annotation should work, based on https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations -- though maybe the `@ExtendWith` annotation needs to be inlined? Not sure...